# Hazelcast IAtomicReference.alter lambda

Tags: lambda, java-8, hazelcast, atomicreference

I am trying to populate another atomic reference based on existing cache.  I want to use lambdas for code simplicity (less boiler code required) but it doesn't seem to be working.

**This works:**

```
class PutFunction implements IFunction<Graph<Long,Long>,Graph<Long,Long>>{
    private Long key;

    public PutFunction(Long key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public Graph<Long,Long> apply(Graph<Long,Long> graph){
        graph.addVertex(key);
        return graph;
    }
}

getGraphCache().alter(new IFunction<Graph<Long,Long>,Graph<Long,Long>>(){
    public Graph<Long,Long> apply(Graph<Long,Long> graph){
       graph.addVertex(event.getValue().getId());
       return graph;
    }
});
```

**When I switch to lambda syntax below it gives serialization error:**

```
getGraphCache().alter((IFunction<Graph<Long, Long>, Graph<Long, Long>>) graph -> {
   graph.removeVertex(event.getValue().getId());
   return graph;
});
```

ERROR 

`com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: Failed to serialize 'com.portal.objects.ObjectGraphEntryListener$$Lambda$61/1840645556'`

Has anybody gotten it to work with lambdas?

[ObjectGraphEntryListener](https://gist.github.com/piloxcodes123/46e6e667df3ba60e227dd5fc884a983b)

[hazelcast.xml](https://gist.github.com/piloxcodes123/132688cfabdf81a546e8c37881ed9d81)

Comment: tried that, gives something like MapImpl not serializable

Comment: Can you please share the implementation of `com.portal.objects.ObjectGraphEntryListener` class and Hazelcast configuration?

Comment: it is linked at the end of the question.  I don't know if it will be useful though

Comment: Is the `org.jgrapht.Graph` implementation you used serializable?

Comment: yes. otherwise the class version wouldn't have worked.

Comment: AbstractBaseGraph<V, E>
    extends
    AbstractGraph<V, E>
    implements
    Graph<V, E>,
    Cloneable,
    Serializable